# How to print variable number of items using turbogears templates

Tags: python-2.7, turbogears2, turbogears

Hello I've been tasked to work on a turbogears project not knowing anything about the webstack. :)

Anyways, I've been going through some turbogears tutorials and I had a question about printing a variable number of items in turbogears.

So, let's say I have a template printing cars a given owner may have.  It will print year, make, model, and color.  An owner may have 1-n cars.

The examples I found on line for printing one car are pretty straight forward:  @expose a function that returns a dictionary containing information about one car.  Then reference the dictionary in a template.

But what if the owner has several cars?  How can I have a template loop over a list of cars?

I am using turbogears2, python 2.7, on debian system.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the whole template documentation on **Genshi** reference (Genshi is the template engine used by TurboGears): http://genshi.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation/xml-templates.html

What you are looking for is the [py:for](http://genshi.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation/xml-templates.html#id3) attribute which will repeat the tag for each item in a list.

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to answer my question in a couple of hours after posting.  Should I post my example?